# How can I get a current account for working as a freelance event manager?

Tags: bank-account, india, current-events

I am planning to do event management as a freelancer. How can I get a current account for this type of work, as I have not registered any company? I need suggestions on how I can proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to visit any Bank and ask to open an current account in individual name.

An individual can also open current account. Understand the terms carefully; there are quite a few things that are charged for current account, plus you will not get any interest on the balance.